# Separate concerns with messages

Tags: events, elm, elm-architecture

I'm trying to make a generic modal that takes as parameters a text to show and an event to send on the `onClick` of the accept button.

There is a cancel button, which shares the hiding functionality with the accept button.

So I tried to send 2 events on the `onClick` of the accept. One for the accept logic and one for the hiding logic. And that's not working, just the first event is working.

I tried another strategy, the hidden event might have an event 
`OnHideModal (Maybe Msg)` so the modal merges both events before the accept and the `OnHide` hides the modal and sends the internal event to continue the processing. 
This seems to me too heavy, because if you have 3 or more logic events all your events must have another `Maybe Msg`.  And I have difficulties making a `Cmd Msg` with the internal events.

It seems peoples advise is to make a `HideAndLogic` event but that would lead to a lot of copying and pasting of the hiding code, one for each logic.
Plus the logic would be tied with the hiding logic which would make it harder to understand. And if I want to send an event for the logic without hiding anything I would have to make another event that copies half the logic of the first. That goes against basic programming good practice, so I think some people maybe have found a better way.
A way that allows these separate logics to be really separated even in progenitor events.

Using Elm 0.18

Comment: Functional programming has a great feature to avoid copying and pasting large blocks of code: functions. If you make, say, two functions `save` and `hide` that each take and return the model, then in your update function you can just write `Accept -> model |> save |> hide` which makes it really obvious what's happening on `Accept`, and the code is nice and DRY.

Comment: That a realy pretty way to write this. But you don't see my point , I don't want to have `save` next to `hide`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making this too complicated.
You need:

```
viewModal : msg -> msg -> Html msg 
viewModal  acceptMsg  cancelMsg = 
  div [] [ ... button [onclick acceptMsg] ...
           ... button [onclick cancelMsg] ...
         ]
```

Then, your main model needs a `shouldShowModal : Bool`, or some other way of deciding if it should show the modal.
The modal will trigger a Msg which you will handle in your event loop.

Comment: Yes, but would like to not mix the accept logic with the hidding, which is a problem of the modal developper not of the logic developper.
I'm wondering if I shoud not make it like that.
```viewModal : Cmd -> Cmd -> Html msg 
viewModal  acceptCmd  cancelCmd = 
  div [] [ ... button [onclick AcceptMsg acceptCmd] ...
           ... button [onclick CancelMsg cancelCmd] ...
         ]
```
Like that the event is managed by the modal, but the effect of the event is parametrizable. When reacting to the event the modal could update to model to set `shouldShowModal=false`

Comment: To be direct, that's not the way it's done in Elm. You're bringing over ideas from other programming paradigms that either will not work, or will cause you much more trouble than they are worth. What I showed you will work, and it's the preferred way of doing things. Here is THE ULTIMATE reference for a Component in Elm. Written by Evan himself. Read this, then study the component code. https://github.com/evancz/elm-sortable-table#usage-rules

Comment: nice link I will read it. But with your model, you have to do the "hidding" in every events you could pass in the cancelMsg. For me, it's still a repetition probleme.

Comment: You aren't repeating code. Any code in a pure language can be refactored into a function. You are bothered that you maybe have to type a bit more code. You should read this too: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/09/17/typing-is-not-a-programming-bottleneck/

Comment: Call twice a function is also repeating code. Imagine you have 15 modal deferents so you have 15 accept events and 15 cancel events. If you are controlling if you have or not to hide modals in theses 15 events it's 15 time more prone to have a bug than if it's just in one right define place.